# Paginating collections of data using Backbone.js in todos.js web-app

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, each, underscore.js

I am working to this web-app, todos.js, which is well documented at this [url](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html).

I would like to add an option in order to display a limited number of items per page.

Here my attempt which works but I am not sure if it is the right way to do this task:

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

    firstPage: 0,
    perPage: 2,
    counter: 0,

......
    addOne: function addOne (todo) 
    {
        var view,
            isIntoRange;

        view = new TodoView({
            model: todo
        });

        isIntoRange = (
            this.counter >= (this.firstPage * this.perPage) 
            &&
            this.counter < (this.firstPage * this.perPage) + this.perPage   
        );

        if (isIntoRange) {             
            this.$("#todo-list").append(view.render().el);
        }
        this.counter += 1;
    },

    addAll: function() {
        Todos.each(this.addOne);
    },
  .....
});
```

Comment: I have yet to use this myself but I've heard good things about [this](http://addyosmani.com/blog/backbone-paginator-new-pagination-components-for-backbone-js/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having said that backbone-paginator is a good choise, I will not modify the method `addOne` for performing this task:

Rather, I will add a new method  `showTasks` that can accept two parameter: `firstPage` and `perPage`

```
    showTasks: function showTasks (firstPage, perPage)
    {
        // your code
    }
```

And then, since this method should be called from a link, I will use `backbone.router` to render the page:

```
   var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
       ....
       linkAction: function(firstPage, perPage){
           taskView.showTasks(firstPage, perPage);
       },
       ....
   });
```